# Лучший способ наследования в NodeJS

Tags: javascript, ооп, node.js

Приветствую. Решил копнуть поглубже и изучить особенности ООП в Node.js. Всё в целом понятно, кроме вопроса о наследовании родительских свойств и методов. Сколько авторов столько и мнений. Как же лучше всего это сделать? И в чём отличия util.inherits от ручного копирования прототипов?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Я за такой вариант:

```
function Base(x) {
  this.x = x;
}

Base.prototype.doSmth = function () {
  console.log(this.x);
};

function Derived(x, y) {
  Base.call(this, x);
  this.y = y;
}

Derived.prototype.__proto__ = Base.prototype;

Derived.prototype.doSmthElse = function () {
  console.log(this.x, this.y);
};
```

Проверка:

```
[
'doSmth' in new Base(3),
'doSmth' in new Derived(3, 7),
!('doSmthElse' in new Base(3)),
'doSmthElse' in new Derived(3, 7),
new Base instanceof Base,
!(new Base instanceof Derived),
new Derived instanceof Base,
new Derived instanceof Derived,
(new Base).constructor === Base,
(new Derived).constructor === Derived,
]
// [true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true]
```

Тепрь объясню, почему.

Варианты, переприсваивающие `Derived.prototype` фактически теряют оригинальный прототип. Они вынуждены самостоятельно восстанавливать свойство `constructor`, если оно нужно. Приведённый выше вариант ничего не ломает. Он сохраняет прототип со всеми свойствами, изменяя непосредственно цепочку наследования.

Раньше такой код было сложно считать хорошим, но сейчас ES6 делает его вполне корректным и правильным. Ещё есть вариант подменять прототип не через `__proto__`, а при помощи `Object.setPrototypeOf` - получится то же самое. Они отличаются только тем, что если в `Object.setPrototypeOf` скормить примитивный тип в качестве нового прототипа, то он кинет исключение, а `__proto__` просто проигнорирует присваивание. Мне больше нравится `__proto__`, но это уже дело вкуса :)

---

UPDATE:

В [node.js v5](https://nodejs.org/en/blog/release/v5.0.0/) пришли к тому же способу наследования - через установку прототипа:

> (Breaking) `util.inherits()` can now work with ES6 classes. This is considered a breaking change because of potential subtle side-effects caused by a change from directly reassigning the prototype of the constructor using `ctor.prototype = Object.create(superCtor.prototype, { constructor: { ... } })` to using `Object.setPrototypeOf(ctor.prototype, superCtor.prototype)` (Michaël Zasso) [#3455](https://github.com/nodejs/node/pull/3455).

Comment: Спасибо за подробный ответ) Если я правильно понял, то Base.call(this,x) это конструктор родительского объекта? Конструктор в конструкторе т.е.

Comment: @BadVolt, это применение родительского конструктора из дочернего для инициализации объекта.

Comment: Обращение к `_proto_` не оптимизируется

Comment: @eicto, да, не оптимизируется. И да, это дорогостоящая операция. Но разве это проблема в данном случае? Это присваивание будет выполнено единожды для каждого насдедования, т. е. грубо говоря, по одному обращению на каждый класс (именно класс, не инстанс!).

Comment: Не оптимизируется не присваивание, а работа с наследником

Comment: @eicto, с каким именно наследником?

Comment: @eicto, кстати, почему бы тебе не дать свой ответ, описав там предпочитаемый тобой вариант?

Comment: читаем сюда, красные рамочки https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/proto

не вижу смысла, наследование в js надо выбирать в зависимости от ситуации. я в свое время много написал по этому поводу.

Comment: по-русски https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/proto

Comment: образение к методам наследуемого прототипа происходит неоптимизированно, проблема не в том как работают оптимизаторы в таком случае (кстати IE показал очень хорошие результаты, а chrome - худшие, при Object.create() ), а в том, что такую ситуацию вообще оптимизировать никто не будет, т.к. это legacy.

Comment: @eicto, не могу найти информацию по влиянию на производительность именно такого использования `__proto__`. В любом случае, если оно на ней как-то сказывается, предполагаю, что они это оптимизируют, потому что это наиболее подходящий и осмысленный вариант его использования.

Comment: @eicto, почему это легаси, если это часть спецификации ES6? Оно же делает то же самое, что `setPrototypeOf`, который вообще только появился в ES6. Если последнее будут оптимизировать, то на `__proto__` оно тоже должно сказаться.

Comment: @Qwertiy,  потому, что это ["Annex B (normative) Additional ECMAScript Features **for Web Browsers**"](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-additional-ecmascript-features-for-web-browsers) т.е. ваш модуль написанный таким образом ещё и не обязательно будет работать в какой-нибудь чисто ecmascript2015 среде.

Comment: @eicto, это именно `__proto__` там, а `setPrototypeOf` общий. Если заменить на него, то всёбудет хорошо? Ну и из v8 `__proto__` никуда не денут.

Comment: Позвольте нам [продолжить обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26010/discussion-between-eicto-and-qwertiy).

Comment: @BadVolt, ответ дополнен.

Comment: @zb', приехали :)